# How to call dispatch without using store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux what would be the correct way to do this

I know that I should use a middle layer but I am not very clear about the concept

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import environment from '../../commons/enviroment.const';
import Loader from '../loader/Loader';

import store from '../../store/store';
import { routes as routesConst, context } from '../../commons/routes/routes.const';

import MandateConsulting from '../mandate-consulting/MandateConsulting';
import { doResetStore } from '../../store/config/actions/actions';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    store.dispatch(doResetStore());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename={context()}>
            <div id={environment.appName} className="ui-kit-reset">
              <Loader />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path={routesConst.etd} component={MandateConsulting} />
                <Route exact path={routesConst.default} component={MandateConsulting} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ACTION

this is the action that should be executed before everything

```
const doResetStore = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: RESET });
    };
};

export {
    doResetStore
};
```

Answer (score 1):

store is where you store your data. components will connect to store to get the data that they need.

you connect the store via

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```

connecting to store or providing the store to the components is react-redux's job.
let say you have your component

```
 class MyComponent {

  }
```

you connect to the store like this:

`enter code here`export default connect()(MyComponent)

Once your component is connected to the store, **dispatch** method is added to the your component's props list.

You use 'dispatch' to change the store, you can think this as `this.setState()`. with dispatch() you are sending a message inside an object to the store and telling store to change itself based on the message that you send.

doResetStore action that you defined above is gonna send this action to the store, this action will go through the reducers that you defined, reducers will see that you send the `type:RESET`. Reducers already know what to do based on 'type" property. once reducer sees 'type:RESET' it will change the store the way how you told it.

You should store your actions in /src/actions directory. Then import them inside components and pass them to dispatch() as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container that mapsDispatchToProps.

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Create a file that imports your component and map your action to your props. Then you will be able to use it without store.